# Send special message to user when they subscribe to AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am looking to send a specific message whenever a user subscribes successfully to AWS SNS. I am thinking of using AWS lambda for this but not sure of the entire flow & code in AWS lambda - python that needs to go in.

Also, once the user sees this message, I want them to also automatically get unsubscribed using the same lambda.

Comment: Miltiple unclear points - `send a.. message whenever a user subscribes .. to AWS SNS`  you mean when an IAM user creates a subscription on a topic? Where the user should see a message?  Send a message to the topic? `once the user sees this message .. automatically get unsubscribed`  How do you plan to detect that a user saw a specific message?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion- I will allow anyone to subscribe to my Sns topic using their email. When a user subscribes to this subscription, I want my lambda to send a email to them like “Thank you for subscribing” and then if possible lambda to delete this user from SNS subscribers list.

Comment: I see multiple issues with the idea - can you guarantee that only a single subscriber is present when sending a message? You may have a look at aws pinpoint for direct sms/email communication. SNS is imho intended for system/internal notification, not for "anyone".   To react on events you can use CloudTrail (send a message on subscribe and remove the subscriber).  `not sure of the entire flow & code` You will have to ask more specific question to get more specific answers